# TeamViewer Mac keyboard layout on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, teamviewer

I'm using Mac OS X 10.9.4 with TeamViewer 9.0.31181.

I use iMac keyboard, but when I remotely control a Ubuntu Desktop, the "delete" button has no response and arrow keys generate abnormal keystrokes in Terminal.

How can I tell TeamViewer / Ubuntu to recognize my keyboard ?

Comment: you got an answer for this?

Comment: Nope. problem persists